# Group By multiple column for sql count statement , in rails environment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two Relations (class)

```
class RecommendedForType < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :name
   has_many :recommended_for_type_restaurants
end
```

And

```
class RecommendedForTypeRestaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :recommended_for_type_id, :restaurant_id, :user_id
   belongs_to :restaurant
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :recommended_for_type

   def self.get_count(rest_id)
     r = RecommendedForTypeRestaurant.where(restaurant_id: rest_id)
     @result =  r.includes(:recommended_for_type)
            .select("recommended_for_type_id, recommended_for_types.name")
            .group ("recommended_tor_type_id, recommended_for_types.name")
            .count
   end

end
```

if I call

```
 RecommendedForTypeRestaurant.get_count(1) # get stat of restaurant_id: 1
```

I get

```
 {"dinner"=>1, "fast food"=>1, "lunch"=>3, "romantic dinner"=>1}
```

My goal is to get both `id` and `name`  of `RecommendTypeFor` in the return result as well. currently i can only make it return either `id` or `name`. Something like this

```
 {{"id" => 1, "name" => "dinner", "count" => 1}, {"id" =>2, "name" => "lunch", "count" => 3} }
```

For sure i can do another round of sql once i get id or name to create that hash but i think that not the efficient way. Appreciate any help or suggestion :)

Answer (score 9):

You need to group separately, try the following group.

```
.group ("recommended_tor_type_id", "recommended_for_types.name").count
```

Comment: But it seems really slow.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that if you remove the `.count` at the end and change the `select` to:

```
.select("count(*), recommended_for_type_id, recommended_for_types.name")
```

You will get an array of models that will have the attributes you need and the count.

You should be able to test it out in the console by do something like this:

```
 r = RecommendedForTypeRestaurant.where(restaurant_id: rest_id)
 @result =  r.includes(:recommended_for_type)
        .select("recommended_for_type_id, recommended_for_types.name, count(*)")
        .group ("recommended_tor_type_id, recommended_for_types.name")

 @result.each do |r|
     puts r.recommended_for_type_id
     puts r.name
     puts r.count
 end
```

Hope it helps!